# how to upgrade jwplayer 5 to 6.x

Tags: upgrade, jwplayer, jwplayer6

My question here is simple : how to upgrade my JWPlayer 5 Pro to the current version which is 6.10. I have my own server where the version 5.6 is located but i cant find out whats the upgrade process. I have read the official documentation but for me it does not look that easy

Thanks folks!

Comment: What does your embed look like currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple "process" for doing the upgrade, and no automation is available. In effect, you need to rewrite your pages to use the embedding methods of JW6, which are radically different from JW5.

A synopsis of the changes: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1404037-migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6

The basic embedding method of JW6: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406723-mp4-video-embed

The embedding options reference: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference

My own collection of simple examples: http://misterneutron.com/